# Dialog method supported in one page but not in another

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui-dialog

I have 2 .NET web pages that have the same popup box in both pages The JavaScript is exactly the same in both pages, I copied the code from the page that works to the other page and it doesn't work. the one that doesn't work gives me the error message:

```
Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js
0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'dialog'.
```

I have tried putting the code at the end of the page, no difference. Best I can tell jquery is being load into the page in the header when I check the page with the IE developer. Hope someone can point me in the right direction.

```
<link href="Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link  href ="~/Styles/Default.css"  rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#dd2875").dialog({
            buttons: {
                "Cancel": function() {
                    $("#dd2875").dialog('close');
                }
            },
            dialogClass: 'myTitleClass',
            draggable: false,
            width: 800,
            height: 400,
            hide: 2000,
            show: 'slidedown',
            hide: 'explode',
            autoOpen: false
        });

        $("#btnNewAccount").click(function(evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            $("#dd2875").dialog('open');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Is it possible that your element `#dd2875` is not on the page?

Comment: Agree with @stackoverfloweth. If you don't have an element with an `id=dd2875`, the script won't have an object to call `dialog()` on.

Comment: Yes it is on the page because it shows up at the bottom of page when the page opens and I checked through the developer and it is there.  I also commented all the code except the click function and put an alert box just to make sure the jquery is working and it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, had to go back and rewrite the page one section at a time to do it.  The problem was a conflict between the JavaScript and the asp validation controls. When I put the control on the page it caused the error with the dialog. I found two solutions to the conflict. I could add the first line in the page load or the second line in the JavaScript either one worked. Thanks for the help in getting me pointed in the right direction.

```
Unobtrusivevalidaionmode = Unobtrusivevalidaionmode .none
or 
$j = $.noConflict;
```

Answer (score 0):

The DOM probably does not contain an element with the ID dd2875,

Verify that `#dd2875` actually exists on the page at the point that you are calling `dialog()`

Comment: The DOM does contain the id dd2875, so I am stumped as to why it's not working.

Comment: Try ‘console.log($("dd2875").length)’ right before you call ‘dialog’. That will tell you definitively if the element is the when it needs to be

Comment: I did not get any response from the code you suggested.  Here is the error messge I get in the console.

Comment: No log means the object we null.

Comment: Yea but why? The div is in the DOM. I have tried rewriting the code with different names and putting the code in different places. and nothing works.  Is there anything in ASP.Net that could interfere.

Answer (score 0):

I entered the code you sent and this is what I got back in the console.

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: Object doesn't support property or method dialog' TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'dialog'
 at Anonymous function (http://localhost:60086/Add_CAC_ID.aspx:14:13)
at mightThrow (http://localhost:60086/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js:3534:10)
at Anonymous function (http://localhost:60086/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js:3602:12) undefined
```